# remain added class after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this fiddle from other questions, and its good to use. The problem is the added class(.active) in button remove when refresh. How can I make it remain even I reload it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wyEq7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="flr-wrap">
<ul>
    <li><a class="button active" data-rel="#content-a" href="#">a button</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" data-rel="#content-b" href="#">b button</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="flr-inner">
    <div class="container" id="content-a">
        AAA
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="content-b">
        BBB
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    // set content on click
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setContent($(this));
});

// set content on load
$('.button.active').length && setContent($('.button.active'));

function setContent($el) {
    $('.button').removeClass('active');
    $('.container').hide();

    $el.addClass('active');
    $($el.data('rel')).show();
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: is this wrapped in a `$( document ).ready()`?

Comment: You need to store the state somewhere, if you want to use a local state then can think about `localStorage`

Comment: The web is stateless.

Comment: it's not wrapped sir

Comment: Local Storage will be good to work in your case. But remember that it will work browser specifically. Do you need it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the active state either in the server(if there is a way to do this) or in the client side(you can use web storage)

To store it in client side

```
// set content on click
$('.button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setContent($(this));
  localStorage.setItem('active-container', $(this).data('rel'));
});

// set content on load
localStorage.getItem('active-container') && setContent($('.button[data-rel="' + localStorage.getItem('active-container') + '"]'));

function setContent($el) {
  $('.button').removeClass('active');
  $('.container').hide();

  $el.addClass('active');
  $($el.data('rel')).show();
}
```

Comment: how can I make it the button is not active and the content is not shown in the first load, I tried to edit your work but it don't work

Answer (score 1):

Added more details to Arun's answer.

Store menu item in local storage after click.

```
$('.menu-item').click(function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem('active-menu-item', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Set active menu item style by adding class 'active' and click the item to go to the active page. It is inside $(document).ready() so that it runs after refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const activeMenuItem = $('.menu-item[href="' + localStorage.getItem('active-menu-item') + '"]').first();
    activeMenuItem && setActiveLink(activeMenuItem);
});

function setActiveLink($el) {
    $el.addClass('active');
    $el.click();
}
```